# JavaScript function not working as intended

Tags: javascript, higher-order-functions

I've been working through a question and need some help!

I've created my own each function below:

```
var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5]; // this will be running through the collection parameter

var each = function (collection, callback) {
 if (Array.isArray(collection)) {
    for (i=0; i<collection.length; i++) {
    callback(collection[i]);
        };
} else {
  for (var property in collection){
    callback(collection[property]);
  }
}
};
```

I've also created my own filter function below:

```
var filter = function(collection, predicate) {
var newArray= [];
  if (each(collection, predicate)) {
    newArray.push(collection[property]);
  };
return newArray;
};


var test = function (item) {
return item > 2;
}; // this will be running through the predicate parameter

filter(myArray, test);
```

What I'm trying to do, without changing the each function or test function, and only the filter function, is leverage the each function in the filter function. What the last line of code is intended to return, is each element of myArray that end up being true under the predicate parameter - in this case, the test function. So, the result should be [3,4,5]. However, I've been just getting the array to print out empty. I know where the error lies - I believe it's here:

```
if (each(collection, predicate))
```

What this line of code is trying to do, is using the each function, iterate over every item in collection using the predicate function, and if that particular item evaluates to true under predicate, the following line will push the element into newArray.

Hope this makes sense!

Comment: Don't forget to declare your local variables with `var` !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `filter` function needs to wrap the predicate in a separate function so it can build its return value:

```
var filter = function(collection, predicate) {
  var newArray= [];
  each(collection, function(element) {
    if (predicate(element)) newArray.push(element);
  });
  return newArray;
};
```

Now *your* callback passed into your `each()` function uses the passed-in test function to check each element of the collection, but it can then use that result to determine whether or not the element should be added to the result.

Answer (score 0):

You're gonna wanna do something like this:

```
var filter = function(collection, predicate) {
  var array = [];
  each(collection, function(item) {
    if(predicate(item))
      array.push(item);
  });
  return array;
};
```

The second element of each is a call back

Comment: The OP is not using Underscore or Lodash.

Comment: @Pointy oops, that underscore was a bad habit, I took it out.